# Why socket throws IOException if I separate it out from the main Activity?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I made a simple program on Android which connects to a server using Socket and receives some data. When I code in this way, it works well:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    EditText ip_box;
    Button login_button;
    TextView text;
    Handler handler;
    final int port = 12121;
    Socket socket;
    String ip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();//omitted

        handler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                String words = (String)msg.obj;
                text.setText((String)msg.obj);
            }
        };

        class GetThread implements Runnable
        {
            public void getMsg()
            {
                try 
                {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    String gotmsg = in.nextLine();
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = gotmsg;
                    MainActivity.this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = "net error";
                    MainActivity.this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = "net error";
                    MainActivity.this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port) , 5000);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                {
                    ...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    ...
                }

                if( socket != null)
                    getMsg();
                else
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ip = ip_box.getText().toString();
                GetThread g = new GetThread();
                new Thread(g).start();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

And what I'm going to do is to make socket connections an independent class. I made the class in this way:

```
public class ClientSocketManager
{
    String ip;
    int port;
    Socket socket;
    Handler handler; //use this to send messages

    /**
     * Thread to get message from server
     * @author Zero
     *
     */
    class GetThread implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while(true)
                {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if(input!=null)
                    {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.obj = input;
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("NetThreadIOException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "net error";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                //System.out.println("NetThreadIOException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "net error";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Thread to login to server
     * @author Zero
     *
     */
    class LoginThread implements Runnable
    {
        boolean ok;
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port) , 5000);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "did not login";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                ok=false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "did not login";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                ok=false;
            }
        }
    }

    public ClientSocketManager(){}

    /**
     * Create a new ClientSocketManager
     * @param _ip
     * @param _port
     * @param _handler
     */
    public ClientSocketManager(String _ip, int _port, Handler _handler)
    {
        ip = _ip;
        port = _port;
        handler = _handler;
    }

    public boolean login()
    {
        LoginThread login_thread = new LoginThread();
        new Thread(login_thread).start();

        return login_thread.ok;

    }

    public void openGetThread()
    {
        GetThread getThread = new GetThread();
        new Thread(getThread).start();
    }
}
```

And in the main Activity, I use the ClientSocketManager like this:

```
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ip = ip_box.getText().toString();
                client_socket_manager = new ClientSocketManager(ip, port, handler);
                boolean logged = client_socket_manager.login();
                //if(!logged)
                //  return;
                client_socket_manager.openGetThread();
            }

        })
```

Now it throws IOException on `String input = in.readLine();`. I'm curious about it. What's the possible reason?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your new class under a new subfolder or something? Maybe now your path changed

Comment: Try `System.out.println("NetThreadIOException" + e.toString() );` and paste the logcat in question.

Comment: @Kedarnath Thank you for your advise, although I solved my problem before trying it out. Next time I'll debug with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason maybe: 
`client_socket_manager.login()` and `client_socket_manager.openGetThread()` started two threads run concurrently to do two actions `login` and `get`. So when you have not logged in yet, the action `get` was performed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it indeed is caused by this problem. I solved it by waiting for the `LoginThread` finishes, then call the `openGetThread()` . It works well now.

Comment: @DarkZero you are welome

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is no guarantee in your code that the GetThread will execute **after** the LoginThread. I see that you have commented the code checking for a logged in status. You need to put that back in.

```
 boolean loggedIn = false;

 class LoginThread implements Runnable
    {
        boolean ok;
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port) , 5000);
                loggedIn = true;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "did not login";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                ok=false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "did not login";
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                ok=false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and later check for this loggeddIn flag before running the GetThread

```
client_socket_manager = new ClientSocketManager(ip, port, handler);                
client_socket_manager.login();
while (true){
     if(loggedIn){
           client_socket_manager.openGetThread();
           break;
      }
      Thread.sleep(1000); //wait 1 sec before retrying
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct solution and code, although I didn't solve it using `sleep()`, instead I chose to use `join()` to wait `LoginThread` finish. I don't have enough rep so I can't vote you up, sorry...